# Expand toggle if label hasClass 'error'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this might be a silly question but I need to expand a toggle on a form if it returns an error. When the form is submitted it reloads the page, and therefore the slidedown is initially hidden.

There is a link to toogle down the form:

```
<span id="slideDownCreateMail"  styleId="createEmail" class="createNewEmailGallery">Expand</span>
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="showCreateNewEmailAccount" >
            <fieldset>
                <h3>Enter mail</h3>
                <p id="createNewEmailAccount">
                    <label for="name">Email:</label>
                    <html:text property="address" styleClass="border" styleId="address" />
                </p>
                <div><one:error property="address" element="label" /></div>

                <p>
                    <label for="mailPassword1">Password:</label>
                    <html:password property="mailPassword1" styleClass="border" styleId="mailPassword1" />
                </p>
                <div><one:error property="mailPassword1" element="label" /></div>

                <p>
                    <label for="mailPassword2">Password (again):</label>
                    <html:password property="mailPassword2" styleClass="border" styleId="mailPassword2" />
                </p>
                <div><one:error property="mailPassword2" element="label" /></div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
```

I am trying to do it with jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#slideDownCreateMail").click(function(){
            $(".showCreateNewEmailAccount").slideToggle("slow");

            /*if (!$(".showCreateNewEmailAccount").hasClass("error"))  {
                $(".showCreateNewEmailAccount").css('display','block');
            }*/
        });
        $('.showCreateNewEmailAccount label').has('error').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

But none of the above seems to work. 
The error is returned in this tag:

```
    <p>
    <label for="mailPassword1">Password</label>
        <html:password property="mailPassword1" styleClass="border" styleId="mailPassword1" />
    </p>
<div><one:error property="mailPassword1" element="label" /></div>
```

Does anyone have any idea what might do the trick? :) 
Thanks.

Comment: Is that html:password asp?

Comment: please add what error is returned at your browser `Console` ?? @PatrickZiebell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more of the HTML I can only guess...

HTML - 
If you can add an ID to your tag

```
<one:error property="mailPassword1" element="label" styleId="errorLabel" />
```

jQuery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if ( $('#errorLabel').hasClass('error') ) {
    $('#errorLabel').css('display', 'block');
  }

});
```

If you cant add a ID onto  element make sure its 100% in `.showCreateNewEmailAccount` and then

EDIT -

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  if ( $('.showCreateNewEmailAccount label').hasClass('error') ) {
    $('.showCreateNewEmailAccount').css('display', 'block');
  }

});
```

Comment: I have updated the question to contain the HTML as well.

Comment: So are you able to add an ID to the label in question?
My 1st jQuery example would work if you could?

Comment: Ahh I saw your fix! That did it! Thank you very much @Mark!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
var $field = $('.showCreateNewEmailAccount');
var hasError = $field.find('label.error').length;

$field.slideToggle(hasError);
```